# Django model: a fieldtype for making a set/list of instances of another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, relation

Consider these three models:

```
class Statement(models.Model):
    statement_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    statement-keywords = ?
    statement-contexts = ?

class Keyword(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    statement = models.ManyToManyField(Statement)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.word

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Context(models.Model):
    context_word = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    keyword = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
    statement = models.ManyToManyField(Statement)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.context_word
```

Every Statement is supposed to have a set of associated Keywords and Contexts. I am also working mainly on the admin interface of this website, and wanted to ensure that someone could enter in keywords and contexts on the same page for updating or submitting a new page.

It would be ideal if I could make statement-keywords hold a set of all `Keywords`'s, and statement_contexts hold a set of all associated keywords to that statement instance, and statement-context hold a set of all `Context`'s associated with that statement. But there are two issues that come up for me:

1. Because Statement is above Keyword and Context, I can't reference Keyword and Context as objects in a manytomany relationship. If I do so, I get an error message. If I move Statement below Keyword and Context, then Keyword and Context would both be unable to make a reference Statement (I would get an error message).
2. I do not know the if there's a fieldtype that could say "this field is going to hold a set of objects," or an alternative to that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need either of those fields. You already have them: they are the reverse relations from the ManyToManyFields on Keyword and Context.

Comment: One of the benefits of having the two fields is for the sake of the admin interface. Right now on the statement submission/update page, no information about the keywords and contexts associated with a statement appears. I know I could make a reverse relation query, but... It would be easiest if the Statements model just had fields for keywords and contexts. I also wouldn't know how to use the reverse relation to change the Statements model or affects its display on admin.

Comment: That is exactly what [inline admins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) are for.